# For loop and Array output confusion. Why is the middle section of this array not the same as the beginning and the end?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I run through this on paper, and I can't figure out why when `list[i]=list[3]`, makes the output 4,0 and not 2,2. Where am I tracing this wrong? Numbers after that don't stack up as I think they should.

The first three and the last three outputs make sense. But the middle 4, I don't understand how they are getting `[4,0], [1,2], [2,1], [0,4]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int list[10]= {2,1,2,4,1,2,0,2,1,2};
    int line[10];

    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
        line[i]= list[9-i];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", list[i], line[i]);

    return 0;
}

output: 
2 2
1 1
2 2
4 0
1 2
2 1
0 4
2 2
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: Why would you expect `list[i] == 2` for `i==3`? `list[3]` starts as 4 and never changes.

Comment: Array indexes are 0-based in C. The first element has index 0. That means that the 4th element has index 3.

Comment: The line array is the reverse of the list array. So read the right column from the bottom to get the same order as the left column from the top.

Comment: @interjay good grief, thank you.

Comment: I was taking the `list [9-i]` and putting that value with the print statement. Thanks guys